# Symfony not save record, persist not run

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I created a simple method for recording products. It injects container and initiates service doctrine. I create a new object Products, I set the name and persist and flush. Product not written to the database. The system log information on the insert but not flush.

Entity hasn't any association
http://pastebin.com/FesW7bQe

Comment: please add your source code to your answer instead of pastebin

Comment: please paste your code here, also add your entity product, method controller and declare your service (if you use that)